# Looping through jQuery objects in a collection without initializing a new jQuery object for each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find myself doing this all the time:

```js
$myElements.each( function(index, currentHtmltmlElement) {
  var $currentJqueryElement = $(currentHtmltmlElement);
  // Working with $currentJqueryElement
});
```

Initializing a new jQuery object in each iteration is a huge performance penalty.

So i thought of doing this instead (credit also goes to decx@freenode):

```js
for (var index = 0; index < $myElements.length; index++) {
  var $currentJqueryElement = $myElements.eq(i);
  // Working with $currentJqueryElement
}
```

But i fixed up a [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-for-eq-vs-each) and this snippet's performance turned out to be identical to that of the first snippet! :(

Both are freaking slow! For really large collections, you could even notice the page freeze.

So i wonder what is the fast way of iterating through jQuery objects in a collection.

The way should also be as convenient to use as possible. This:

```js
$items.each$item( function( $item, index ) { /* Working with $item directly. */ });
```

would be *way* better than the ancient `for (var i=0...` ineptitude.

### UPD 2014-05-27

Here's an example. Imagine that you have a number of jQuery UI Sliders:

```js
<div class="my-slider"></div>
<div class="my-slider"></div>
<div class="my-slider"></div>
```

```js
$sliders = $('.my-slider').slider();
```

Now you would like to log to console the value of each slider. You have to do:

```js
$sliders.each( function(index, htmlSlider) {
  $current_slider = $(htmlSlider); // This step is a huge performance penalty

  console.log(
    $current_slider.slider('value')
  );
});
```

So the task is to get rid of the performance penalty.

You can't simply do `$sliders.slider('value')` because this will output the value only of the first slider in the collection.

You can't revert to vanilla JS inside the loop because you can't access a jQuery widget without a jQuery object.

So far, all these approaches...

- `$sliders.each( function(index, htmlSlider) { htmlSlider });`
- `$sliders.each( function() { this });`
- `for (var i = 0; i < $sliders.length; i++) { $sliders.eq(i); }`
- `$.each`, `$.makeArray`, `$.map`, etc

...work with `$sliders`'s underlying array of HTML elements and require a time-costy `$( )` initialization to access jQuery features.

Comment: Ever heard of `$(this)`? `$items.each(function() {//$(this) is a jQuery representation of the current element});`

Comment: `$foo.each( function() { $(this) }` and `$foo.each( function(i, e) { $(e) }` are absolutely identical both technically and performance-wise. The only difference is that using an argument always works, whereas `this` might be not available due to scope proxying or using `=>` in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be happy if you prove me wrong, but i came to a conclusion that **a jQuery collection is a uniform object that cannot be iterated through** and only the HTML elements it represents are stored as separate entities that can be enumerated. You can't split a jQuery collection into parts directly, you can only create new ones out of separate HTML elements.

Thus, revert to native JS features inside the loop whenever possible to improve performance.

Comment: Interesting topic. See edit at post. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @guest271314 You've got my upvote, but all your snippets iterate through HTML elements, without solivng the problem. I've update my question with an explicit example. Please have a look and reply back.

Comment: Tried to create jsfiddle with `jquery` `ui` at http://jsfiddle.net/52azq/ . Not tried `slider` `widget` pieces. If can create jsfiddle ok, nice, if not, would `.data()`, or `.text()`, (or other method ?) be ok substitute for `slider("value")` ? Thanks

Comment: Here's a working fiddle for you to play with: http://jsbin.com/cinay/3/edit?html,js,output When slicing the jQuery collection, look which prototype the parts of the collection have. If the `__proto__` property is Object, then you're good. If it's `HTMLDivElement`, you're losing it.

Comment: @guest271314, i've tested the `.eq()` approach and its performance proved itself to be identical to that of `$(this)`. See links to JSPerf in the question and answers.

Comment: Ok, not sure exactly what the requirement is ? We've a) eliminated the `$()` wrapper by utilizing the `promise` object , is next step b) create a custom jquery object or method which mimics iteration , while maximizing performance ? One of the existing internal or core jquery methods _may_ achieve this, yet perhaps simpler to create the function, method, or "plugin" signature which achieves the desired results - composing the piece with performance as the core requirement ? fwiw, the returned `promise` object from `$.when()` contains the entire set of `sliders`. Thanks

Comment: The requirement is to improve performance of iterating through items of a jQuery collection by excluding reinitialization of a jQuery object on every HTML element of the collection. Your `.eq()` suggestion *seemed* to be a solution and it was the first thing that i had checked before posting the question. Unfortunately, it seems that `.eq()` does `$(this)` internally as **it introduces absolutely no performance benefit**. As for promises, i don't see how adding them to the code helps. They seem to make the code more complicated without giving any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `this` keyword? Seems to be fastest, not to mention (objectively) easiest to understand.

```
$myElements.each( function() {
  var $currentJqueryElement = $(this);
});
```

http://jsperf.com/jquery-for-eq-vs-each/3

If performance is a problem, why not skip out on jQuery and use pure JS?

**Answer to update**

If you want to get the slider values (which seem to be just the amount of `css style "left"` , you could do something such as:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('my-slider');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    console.log(elems[i].style.left); // logs : xx.xx%
}
```

Would it be faster? Maybe. Will the approach fit in all use cases? Most likely not, but for that specific question it should work.

Comment: You can tell from your own test that performance-wise your variant is identical to mine.

Comment: "@PeteTNT If performance is a problem, why not skip out on jQuery and use pure JS?" -- i thought there's a solution for this. If the performance penalty is intrinsic to jQuery collections, i will probably have to revert to native JS where possible (and worth the effort).

Comment: +1 on skip out on jQuery to win performance. My scripts are 10times faster with nativeJS (but not cross-browser lol).

Comment: Pete TNT, A1rPun, please suggest a nativeJS way of calling methods on jQuery widgets. See the updated question for an example.

Comment: See my updated answer, it won't fit every use case, and you can't easily call methods on jQuery widgets but if the values are visible in the markup getting them would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.each($p, function(i, v) {
  test = $(v)
})
```

`for + eq() : 702`

`each() : 722`

`this : 718`

`$.each() : 757 ("fastest")`

http://jsperf.com/jquery-for-eq-vs-each/5

Edit

> *You can't split a jQuery collection into parts directly, you can only create new ones out of separate HTML elements. -lolmaus - Andrey
>   Mikhaylov*

Try (at `console`, this page)

```
$("div"); // jQuery `collection` ? approx. `222` members, changes

// `split` 1st `101` members of jquery `obj`, or `collection` 
var split_jq_obj_1 = $("div").slice(0, 111); 

// `split` 2nd `101` members of jquery `obj`, or `collection` 
var split_jq_obj_2 = $("div").slice(-111); 

// Note `prevObject` and `selector` properties of  `jQuery` `object`
// `split_jq_obj_1` and `split_jq_obj_2` 
// `prevObject: e.fn.e.init[222]` , `selector: "div.slice(0,111)"`, 
// `prevObject: e.fn.e.init[222]`, `selector: "div.slice(-111)"`) 


// check results 
console.log($("div"), split_jq_obj_1, split_jq_obj_2);         
console.log($("div").length, split_jq_obj_1.length, split_jq_obj_2.length);
```

other possible approaches

```
// `jquery` `object`, or `objects` 
var arr = $.makeArray($.map($("div"), function(value, index) {
  return ( index < 111 ? [$(value)] : null )
}), $.map($("div"), function(value, index) {
  return ( index >= 111 ? [$(value)] : null )
}));

console.log(arr); // `collection` of `jQuery` `objects`

// iterate `jquery` object`, or `objects`, 
// find `length` of `class` `item-content`
$.each($(arr), function(index, value) {
  console.log($(value).find(".item-content").length) // `29` (see `iteration` at `console`)
});

// check results
$(".item-content").length; // `29`
```

Edit 2014-05-28

Try this (pattern)

```
$(function () {
    var sliders = $('.sliiider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    });

    $('html').click(function () {
        $.when(sliders)
            .then(function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                // `$()` jQuery `wrapper` _not_ utilized,
                // not certain about quantifying `cost`, if any,
                // of utilizing jquery's `deferred` `object`s
                // test by sliding several `sliders`,
                // then `click` `document`, or `html`
                console.log(data.eq(i).slider("value"))
            };
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8gVee/

fwiw, this pattern also appears to work, again *without* utilizing jquery's `init` wrapper `$()`

```
$(function () {
    var sliders = $('.sliiider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    });

    $('html').click(function () {
        $.when(sliders)
            .then(function (data) {
            // Note, 2nd parameter to `.each()` not utilized, here
            data.each(function (i) {  
                // `$()` jQuery `init` `wrapper` _not_ utilized, 
                // within `.each()` `loop`,
                // same result as utilizing `for` loop,
                // "performance", or "fastest" not tested as yet
                console.log(data.eq(i).slider("value"));
            })
        });
    });
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/G944X/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, a 4% performance gain is negligible. Could even be a measurement error.

Comment: Another possible approach is simply to utilize `$("p")` ? or `$("p[class^=foo]")`,  ? Still a "collection". Have found this useful as well `var arr = $.makeArray($("p"))` -> `arr[7]`, etc. `nth-of-type` can also be utilized to filter through a collection. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: You are coorect about a possible measurement error; `$.each()` was not fastest "each" run. Though it appeared to be "fastest" approximately 3 out of 4 runs. Thanks, again

Comment: `makeArray` is of no use because it spawns an array of HTML elements, not jQuery objects.