# Why $.each() is slower than for loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery, performance, for-loop, callback, each

Some [sources](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551/) ask to prefer **"for loop over $.each()"** in jquery since  **$.each()** is slower than for loop in  [ops/sec](http://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each/9/)

Is this because of callback function of **$.each()?**

Can anybody explain Why $.each() is slower than for loop in jquery and In which case i have to choose for **loop over  $.each() or vice verse** ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: $.each helps in synchronous execution, Next iteration called when the 1st function completes. For loop doesnt wait for that.

Comment: @SSS `for` loops are not asynchronous...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872678/looping-through-jquery-objects-in-a-collection-without-initalizing-a-new-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code comes from within the `jQuery.each` method:

```
for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
    value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );
    if ( value === false ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

So *inside* the `jQuery.each` function is a `for` loop. It is completely inevitable that it should be slower, especially given that it uses `Function#call`.

So yes, the `for` loop will be faster. But there are still use-cases for the jQuery method. First, because it is very rarely *significantly* slower. If you have performance-critical code, use the `for` loop. But very frequently there will be zero discernable difference between the native code and the jQuery code. According to the jsPerf link you give, the `for` loop is about 30 times faster. But on my (not very powerful) system it's the difference between `0.0015` of a second and `0.000052` of a second. The code within the loop will be far more significant; you probably won't notice the difference.

Second, the jQuery method (like the native `Array.forEach` method) uses functions for each iteration of the loop, so it changes the scope, whereas `for` loops do not. This is frequently desirable, e.g. when you need a closure or when you want to limit a variable to a small section of your code.

So basically you should use `for` loops when performance *really* matters and use jQuery's equivalents when it makes your life easier.